# Convergence test on $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Question**
Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}$$
for each of the following convergence tests, state with justification if the test proves convergence, divergence or confirms neither

- The Ratio Test
- The Comparison Test

**My attempt at an Answer**
*The Ratio test* states that a series is:
 - absolutely convergent if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lvert u_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert u_n\rvert}<1$,
 - divergent if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lvert u_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert u_n\rvert}>1$, and
 - undefined if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lvert u_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert u_n\rvert}=1$

so
$$u_n=\frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}$$
$$u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2\ln{(n+1)}}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lvert\frac{1}{(n+1)^2\ln{(n+1)}}\rvert}{\lvert\frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}\rvert}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2\ln{(n)}}{(n+1)^2\ln{(n+1)}}$$
but
$$n^2\ln{(n)}<(n+1)^2\ln{(n+1)}$$
$$\color{red}{\therefore\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2\ln{(n)}}{(n+1)^2\ln{(n+1)}}<1}$$
<s>and so absolutely convergent</s> 
but
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2\ln{(n)}}{(n+1)^2\ln{(n+1)}}=1$$
and so is undefined for this test.
$\square$

*The comparison test* has me stumped though.
How do I break $\frac{1}{n^2\ln{n}}$ into multiple terms to perform the comparison test?

Comment: Your limit is actually $1$, not $<1$, which changes matters considerably. Compare with $\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: For the regions of convergence see for example https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the comparison test, just note that $ \dfrac{1}{n^2 \log n} < \dfrac{2}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq 2.$

Your application of the ratio test is incorrect as well - just because $a_n < b_n $ holds doesn't mean $\lim a_n < \lim b_n $ , strict equality can hold as well. Try to think of an example. It turns out your limit is actually equal to $1$ so the ratio test is inconclusive.

Comment: Could you please expand on the ratio test? Sorry for asking, but I still need to see all the steps please.

Comment: As you wrote in your post, if the limit in the ratio test is <1, we have converge, if it is >1 then we have diverge, but if it is equal to 1 then we don't know which one. Here, we have the 3rd situation. In your post you got to $n^2 \ln n < (n+1)^2 \ln n+1 $, so their ratio is $<1$, but then you incorrectly concluded that the *limit* of the ratio is $<1.$ Eg if $a_n = n $, $b_n=n+1$ then $a_n < b_n $ but $\lim a_n/b_n =1.$

Comment: I don't agree (probably because I'm misunderstanding something ;-): So even when $n\rightarrow\infty$ the numerator would be less that the denominator due to the $+1$ and hence < 1. Are we saying that it is so close that we asume that its $=1$?

Comment: @Gineer We say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = L$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is some $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $| x_n - L|< \epsilon.$ In plain terms: We say the limit of a sequence is $L$ is for any chosen error, even if we pick it to be very small, the sequence eventually remains within our small allowed error.

Comment: So for the example in my previous comment, the limit is $1$ because for any $\epsilon>0$ you give me, I can find an $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, we have $| a_n/b_n - 1|<\epsilon.$ Indeed, $|a_n/b_n -1| = 1/(n+1)$ so for any given $\epsilon>0$, I say let $n_0 = 1/\epsilon.$ Then certainly for all $n>n_0$ we can see that $|a_n/b_n -1|<\epsilon.$ Thus the limit is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Try $$\frac{1}{n^2\ln n}<\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Comment: For $n>2$. $\qquad$

Comment: In Rudin(Mathematical Analysis), there is a theorem that says: If $a_k$ are non negative and nonincreasing, $\sum a_k$ converges iff $\sum 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges.

Comment: @GautamShenoy That would be the Cauchy Condensation test.

Answer (score 3):

For $n>2$ tryto use the integral test over $[2,+\infty)$ in which $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2\log (x)}$.